# SEPARAR DATOS EN JASPERPORT

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2, jasper-reports

tengo un problema al momento de crear un reporte en JasperReport , lo que pasa  es que tengo que usar dos tablas de una base de datos y combinar la informacion de ambas tablas en un reporte
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

algo mas o menos asi , pero al momento de hacer el reporte se hace de la siguiente manera
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero lograr es que en cada pagina se muestre en la parte de arriba el numero de un tren por ejemplo  "091/092" y después muestre otros datos pero que llegue al numero 9 y despues aparezca otro tren  "093/091" y luego otros 9 datos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el archivo jrxml

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, Mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta y tambien evitarás recibir votos negativos, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, en formato texto, y solo la parte involucrada en el problema, si es posible, que se pueda ejecutar. Sería bueno que hagas el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Hola, deberías editar tu pregunta y agregar el código (como texto) que crees que genera el problema.